# Is it possible to get Debian Lenny running yet?

Tags: linux, debian, package-managers, lenny

I need to install Debian Lenny i386 as a VM in VMWare. The problem is that when searching for Archive Mirrors, I always get the error message

> Bad archive mirror
>
> The specified Debian archive mirror is either not available, or does not
> have a valid Release file on it

I tried like 20 different mirrors, all with the same result.

A few steps earlier in the installation progress the network is set up and I do net get any error messages. Also when I finish the installation without an archive mirror, I can successfully ping stuff. So the network seems to be fine.

I also tried to set `http://httpredir.debian.org/` in the sources.list so if I understood correctly, debian should automatically choose a mirror. But I still can't do stuff like `apt-get update`.

Is it possible that Lenny is so old it's simply not supported? Or is there some trick to get it running as VM?

Comment: This is a question for super-user instead of stackoverflow. However, old packages can be found in the archives: `deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny contrib main non-free`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian 5 was discontinued, you need to use the archive repo server:

> deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib
>
> deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny main non-free contrib
>
> deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free
>
> deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free
>
> deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
>
> deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
>
> deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main contrib non-free

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer despite that not being the best place to ask the question. It worked to use those!